# how to save features and their values used in decision trees in pickle file along with model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

suppose I have a decision tree classifier, built with sklearn library.
I to save the model file into a pickle,
now, I load it again to see the model descriptors i.e, all the features and their values , i am getting only model definition.

this is the code:

```
import pickle
with open("./decision_treee.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    pickle_model = pickle.load(f)
print(pickle_model)
```

this is what I get as output:

```
`DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                   max_depth=7, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                   min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                   min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=2,
                   min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                   random_state=50, splitter='best')`
```

how do I get the features and their values which make decisions, and finally classify a given data input?
like this.

```
|--- feature1<= 1.50

|   |--- feature2<= 0.88
|   |   |--- feature3<= 0.05
|   |   |   |--- feat4<= 0.58
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |   |--- feat4>  0.58
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |--- feat3>  0.05
|   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |--- feat2>  0.88
|   |   |--- class: 0.0
|--- feat1>  1.50
|   |--- feat5<= 0.22
|   |   |--- feat6<= 0.90
|   |   |   |--- feat7<= 0.1
|   |   |   |   |   |--- other_chars >  0.14
|   |   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0.0
|   |   |--- feat3>  0.90
|   |   |   |--- feat5<= 0.13
|   |   |   |   |--- feat6<= 0.25
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |   |   |--- feat6>  0.25
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0.0
```

Is it possible to save these features and their values in a pickle file and not just model definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pickled trained model, it should contain all features and values after loading. Use sklearn.tree.export_text() to check if your model loaded correctly.